# Special character in dataproc yarn properties

Tags: bash, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I found this example of command to create dataproc cluster and setting some yarn properties.

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster_name \
  --bucket="profiling-job-default" \
  --zone=europe-west1-c \
  --master-boot-disk-size=500GB \
  --worker-boot-disk-size=500GB \
  --master-machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
  --num-workers=10 \
  --worker-machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
  --initialization-actions gs://custom_init_gcp.sh \
  --metadata MINICONDA_VARIANT=2 \
  --properties=^--^yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores=4--capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

I notice a particular string `^--^` before the property key-value: `yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores=4`.

What does `^--^` mean? It is a sort of escape for `--`?
Where is this documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `gcloud` syntax for list and dictionary type values [escaping](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/escaping).

It means that characters specified between `^` are treated as values and key-values delimiter for list and dictionary flags.